# Number written as array to binary

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

I have to deal with very big numbers written in 2^k base. I made an array-based representation, e.g. number 751 is represented as long[] {0, 7, 5, 1}, -751 is long[] {1, 7, 5, 0}.

My question is how to convert them to binary representation? I would like to avoid transforming them into BigInteger and dividing.
In case of negative numbers I need two's complement.

Comment: NOTE : To store a short number, you use 4longs. This is not really memory friendly.

Comment: there is no out of the box method for converting such arrays into anything... you will  end up dividing and moduling those values....

Comment: Lot of tutorials/courses on the subject on the web...

Comment: So you're asking to help converting decimal to binary?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way a base-2^k encoding; it is a base-10 encoding:

> 751 is represented as long[] {0, 7, 5, 1} in base 10, since
>   751 is 7*10^2 + 7*10^1 + 1*10^0

This *would* be a base-16 encoding:

> 1873 is represented as long[] {0, 7, 5, 1} in base 16, since
>    1873 is 7*16^2 + 5*16^1 + 1*16^0

Assuming a `long[] n` is in base 2^k, so that

```
value = n[0]*(2^(k*(n.length-1)) + ... + [n.length-1]
```

(Which is NOT what you would do in real life: you would use BigInteger)

then conversion to binary is simple enough:

```
StringBuilder binaryString = new StringBuilder();
for (long l : n) {
   binaryString.append(binaryFor(l));
}
```

that is, just converting each array element to a binary string and concatenating everything will work.

A better way of encoding integers in arrays is to place the units at n[0], instead of at n[length-1]; you would then need  to use prepend instead of append.